# Magento - getItemsCount() return number of difference products

Tags: magento-1.7

the function `getItemsCount()` supposes to return number of products in the current cart. But in my case it returns the number of **difference** products instead. Like in the image below, it should return 3, it returns 2 instead.

[image]

Is there any solution for this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 $totalQuantity = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getItemsQty();
```

Read more @ http://wabism.com/magento-shopping-cart-total-quantity-vs-total-items/